# How to loop through each row of gridview and read the cells in c# windows application

Tags: datagridview, foreach

Can anyone help me with this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvCSPanel.Rows)
{

}
```

In this I want to read the rows and columns data.

It is in windows application

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataGridViewRow.Cells[int columnIndex].Value` or `dgvCSPanel[int columnIndex, int rowIndex].Value`.